# Log-normal random variables and the distribution of shocks in AR(1) model

Tags: lognormal-distribution, t-distribution

Assume, X and Y are jointly lognormally distributied and let X follow AR(1) process:

$$X_{t+1} = \mu_t + \alpha X_t+ u_{t+1},$$

$\alpha < 1$.
Thereafter, I can't come up with an answer to the two questions:

1). Can it be possible that errors from AR(1) process follow Student t-distribution taking into account **only** the fact that X and Y are jointly lognormal and **not** knowing the true (separate) distribution of X?

2). Can we claim that the only possible distribution of X is lognormal knowing that X and Y are jointly lognormal?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't have the $X_i$ all being lognormal and related by $X_{t+1} = \mu_t + X_t+ u_{t+1}$ unless $u$ depends on $X$ in a very particular way (that would make it useless as a noise term).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure, but I will give my best, starting with the second question.

2nd Question: $X$, $Y$ being jointly log-normal means that $\ln{X}$ and $\ln{Y}$ are jointly normal. But $\ln{X}$ and $\ln{Y}$ each have to follow a univariate normal to be jointly normal (on the other hand, if they are each marginally normal, they are not necessarily jointly normal... (e.g. copula)).

1st Question:  I would say no. you can expand $Y_{t+1}=\mu_t + \alpha(\mu_{t-1}+\alpha Y_{t-1} + u_{t}) + u_{t+1}$. And so on. You then realize that  $Y_{t+1}$ can be expressed as an infinite sum of $u$s. Then some central limit theorem says that this approaches the normal.

It is not the simplest Lindeberg-Levy CLT because the $u$s are slightly transformed (and not identically distributed), but the asymptotic distribution will nevertheless be normal if the $u$s have finite variance. So my guess is that if you have $u$s distributed with t-Student with at least 3 degrees of freedom (and hence finite variance), you will have normal and cannot have log-normal. For 1-2 DFs, which is actually pretty interesting in many appications, I am not entirely sure. But I would say no, as lognormal is not symetrical.

Comment: Sorry, I made a stupid mistake, I forgot to put alpha in there, shame on me! About the second question -- thanks! (By the way, can you give me some reference maybe?)

Comment: About the first one -- I came to the following conslusion: at time $t$ $X_{t}$ is known, and $X_{t+1}$ with $u_{t+1}$ are random. Then, if r.v. on the LHS have lognormal distr. then the r.v. on the RHS should have exactly the same distribution. Do you think it makes sense?

Comment: About second question - It is actually easy to show that differentiating bivariate normal by one variable gives the marginal distribution of the other variable - and the variable is normal (the variance and mean changes slightly for the marginal, though). A similar thing can be done for lognormal.